# C++ Phidget eventhandler undefined reference 'linker'

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I am getting the following errors. Based on the last line I believe it a linker error. However, I really don't know what I am talking about. :) I'm a beginner. If you happen to spot any other crappy points please let me know!

error: undefined reference to `AttachHandler(_CPhidget*, void*)'
error: undefined reference to`DetachHandler(_CPhidget*, void*)' 
error: undefined reference to `ErrorHandler(_CPhidget*, void*, int, char const*)'
error: undefined reference to`Data(_CPhidgetBridge*, void*, int, double)'
:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I have a header file named eventhandlers.h that contains:

```
#ifndef EVENTHANDLERS_H
#define EVENTHANDLERS_H

#include <phidget21.h>


int CCONV AttachHandler(CPhidgetHandle SENSOR, void *userptr);
int CCONV DetachHandler(CPhidgetHandle SENSOR, void *userptr);
int CCONV ErrorHandler(CPhidgetHandle SENSOR, void *userptr, int ErrorCode, const char *DESCR);
int CCONV Data(CPhidgetBridgeHandle SENSOR, void *userptr, int index, double val);


#endif // EVENTHANDLERS_H
```

I am trying to pass the AttachHandler, and others as a parameter of CPhidget_Set_OnAttach_Handler() in a source file name quadbridge.cpp *PARTIAL CODE*:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "quadbridge.h"
#include "eventhandlers.h"

QuadBridge::QuadBridge(int numOfSensors, int PhidgetID)
{

this->SERIAL = 140800;
//this->SERIAL = 137723;

this->bridge = 0;
CPhidgetBridge_create(&bridge);
setEventHandlers();

if(setAttachController(PhidgetID))
{
    getNumOfSensorsAttached(numOfSensors);
    initSensors();
}
else
{
    exit(1);
}

}

QuadBridge::~QuadBridge()
{
CPhidget_close((CPhidgetHandle)bridge);
CPhidget_delete((CPhidgetHandle)bridge);
}

void QuadBridge::setEventHandlers()
{
CPhidget_set_OnAttach_Handler((CPhidgetHandle)bridge, AttachHandler, 0);
CPhidget_set_OnDetach_Handler((CPhidgetHandle)bridge, DetachHandler, 0);
CPhidget_set_OnError_Handler((CPhidgetHandle)bridge, ErrorHandler, 0);

CPhidgetBridge_set_OnBridgeData_Handler(bridge, Data, 0);

CPhidget_open((CPhidgetHandle)bridge, SERIAL);
}
```

And finally - I get the whole thing rolling in main.

```
#include "palmtools.h"
#include "QuadBridge.h"
#include <QApplication>

QuadBridge *qb;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
PalmTools w;
w.show();

qb = new QuadBridge(4);

return a.exec();
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can see that there are declarations of

```
int CCONV AttachHandler(CPhidgetHandle SENSOR, void *userptr); //etc
```

and compiler can compile the source code which calls declared functions. However, in the linking step, linker can't find definitions of these functions to include them into output file - since they are not found in file which compiler has passed to it. Since you are using 3rd party library, these functions comes precompiled in "library file" which you need to include in your linking step.

If you are using Visual Studio, right click the project and open properties. Within `Linker` -> `Input` -> `Additional Dependencies` add name of your lib file which contains missing definitions (`phidget21.lib`, I assume). Also, make sure linker's library path contains folder with that file (you can set this in property page under the `VC++ Directories` tab).

Comment: Thanks for the lead. Unfortunately I am not using VS. I am using linux. I added the following line to my QT make file, but it didn't help. LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../usr/lib/ -lphidget21

Comment: @atomSmasher try to point to the so file with absolute path for testing: `LIBS += /usr/lib/phidget21.so` or similar and run qmake again.

Comment: If I point directly to the .a or .so library I get a ton of undefined reference errors. I have decided it has something to do with this QT makefile and how it looks for the libraries. To make sure phidget was working I compiled a simple test program supplied by Phidget using the terminal. It works fine with gcc compiler.

Comment: @atomSmasher just try to modify Qt's pro file, and not the makefile itself. I will see if I can help in hour or so.